# Use plupload multiple times on single form

Tags: jquery, plupload

I am using plupload. I want to upload images on first upload link and then upload documents on second link. I am doing this in wordpress template file. So how do I implement this using plupload??
This is my js code...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 "use strict";

  if (typeof(plupload) !== 'undefined') {


        var uploader = new plupload.Uploader(ajax_vars.plupload);

        uploader.init();

        uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {

            $.each(files, function (i, file) {
             //   console.log('append'+file.id );


                $('#aaiu-upload-imagelist').append(
                    '<div id="' + file.id + '">' +
                        file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b>' +
                        '</div>');
            });

            up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
            uploader.start();
        });




                       uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function (up, file) {
            $('#' + file.id + " b").html(file.percent + "%");
        });



        // On erro occur
        uploader.bind('Error', function (up, err) {
            $('#aaiu-upload-imagelist').append("<div>Error: " + err.code +
                ", Message: " + err.message +
                (err.file ? ", File: " + err.file.name : "") +
                "</div>"
            );
            up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
        });



        uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, response) {

            var result = $.parseJSON(response.response);
           // console.log(result);

            $('#' + file.id).remove();
            if (result.success) {               
                $('#profile-image').css('background-image','url("'+result.html+'")');
                $('#profile-image').attr('data-profileurl',result.html);
                $('#profile-image_id').val(result.attach);

                var all_id=$('#attachid').val();
                all_id=all_id+","+result.attach;
                $('#attachid').val(all_id);
                $('#imagelist').append('<div class="uploaded_images" data-
 imageid="'+result.attach+'"><img src="'+result.html+'" alt="thumb" /><i class="fa
 deleter fa-trash-o"></i> </div>');
                delete_binder();
                thumb_setter();

            }

        });




        $('#aaiu-uploader').click(function (e) {

                  uploader.start();
                  e.preventDefault();
              });

        $('#aaiu-uploader2').click(function (e) {            
                  uploader.start();                      
                  e.preventDefault();
              });


  }

  });
```

This is my template file code for first upload link, it works perfectly...

```
<div id="upload-container">                 
                    <div id="aaiu-upload-container">                 

                        <div id="aaiu-upload-imagelist">
                            <ul id="aaiu-ul-list" class="aaiu-upload-list"></ul>
                        </div>

                        <div id="imagelist">
                        <?php 
                            if($images!=''){
                                print $images;
                            }
                        ?>  
                        </div>
                        <a id="aaiu-uploader" class="aaiu_button" href="#"><?php 
 _e('*Select Images (mandatory)','wpestate');?></a>
                        <input type="hidden" name="attachid" id="attachid" value="<?php
  echo $attachid;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="attachthumb" id="attachthumb" 
 value="<?php echo $thumbid;?>">
                    </div>
                    <span class="upload_explain"><?php _e('*click to set the featured 
   image','wpestate');?></span>
                </div>
        </div>
```

This is code for second upload link....

```
 <div id="upload-container">                 
                    <div id="aaiu-upload-container">                 

                        <div id="aaiu-upload-imagelist">
                            <ul id="aaiu-ul-list" class="aaiu-upload-list"></ul>
                        </div>


                        <a id="aaiu-uploader" class="aaiu_button" href="#"><?php 
_e('*Select Documents (mandatory)','wpestate');?></a>
                        <input type="hidden" name="docid" id="docid" value="<?php echo
  $docid;?>">

                                               </div>

                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers..Do You have any idea about this??

Comment: do you get any Errors ?

Comment: First link work perfectly..but when I clcik on second link It shows # in url..I dont get any errors...

Comment: because you have duplicate DIV ID's try to change the ID of the second uploader link

Comment: I tried that..but no luck...

Comment: when you change the ID of the second uploader you need to create new plupload jQuery functions assigned to the second uploader ID , have you tried this too ?

Comment: rename the second uploader id="aaiu-uploader" to id="aaiu-uploader2"

Comment: already exists in your code `$('#aaiu-uploader2').click(function (e) {            
                  uploader.start();                      
                  e.preventDefault();
              });`